# is there a way to fix this tree? (self-balancing-binary-search python)

Tags: python, list, binary-tree

When trying to print a tree the root takes the value of 20 instead of 80
I guess the problem is inside the library near line 297 bur can't figure out how

```
from self_balancing_binary_search_tree import SBBST

ST = SBBST()

nums = [80,3,20,95,70] # random numbers

ST = SBBST(nums)

print(ST)
```

Comment: Why do you think that the value of the root should be 80?

Comment: And why do you think that it has something to do with line 297 of the library? What is special about this line?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know,

- 80 is created as root
- then 3 is inserted to the left of root
- then 20 is inserted to the right of 3.
- We will apply LR rotation
- 20 becomes the root, 3 is left, 80 is right.
- then inserting 95 at the right of 80 and 70 at left of 80.

hence 20 is root.

Hope this solves any confusion here.
:D